# Wix Majorupgrade and keep dynamically generated files on uninstall

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer

I have two problems here that I can't wrap my head around

The first : I have dynamically generated database files that I want to keep on uninstall.
The second : On Upgrade, no files are replaced at all.

What I do for a new upgrade : Just bump the release version from 1.0.1 to 1.0.2.

Here is my wix file:

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
 xmlns:netfx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/NetFxExtension">
<Product Id="*" Name="St Mary Attendnace Mangement" Language="1033" Version="1.0.2" Manufacturer="Shady Atef"
       UpgradeCode="UPGRADECODE">
<Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />
<PropertyRef Id="NETFRAMEWORK45" />
<Condition
  Message='This setup requires Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 package or greater needs to be installed for this installation to continue.'>
  <![CDATA[Installed OR NETFRAMEWORK45]]>
</Condition>
<MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed."
              Schedule="afterInstallExecute" />
<MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes" />


<Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="St_Mary_Attendance_Setup" Level="1">
  <ComponentGroupRef Id="C_CommonAssemblies" />

  <ComponentRef Id="ApplicationShortcuts" />

</Feature>

<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
    <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="St Mary Attendnace Mangement" />
  </Directory>
  <Directory Id="ProgramMenuFolder">
    <Directory Id="ProgramMenuSubfolder" Name="St Mary Attendnace Mangement">
      <Component Id="ApplicationShortcuts" Guid="ED28E3D6-5365-48E7-BD76-B3295099CF47">
        <Shortcut Id="ApplicationStartMenuShortcut"
                  Name="St Mary Attendance Mangement-Shortcut"
                  Description="Manage your attendance easily"
                  Target="[#fil54A6944D4CD4C2F739233096DDDBD757]"
                  WorkingDirectory="INSTALLFOLDER" />
        <RemoveFolder Id="ProgramMenuSubfolder" On="uninstall" />
        <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\ShadyAtef\StMaryChurchAttendance" Name="installed" Type="integer"
                       Value="1"
                       KeyPath="yes" />
      </Component>
    </Directory>
  </Directory>
</Directory>

</Product>
</Wix>
```

Note : `C_CommonAssemblies` is generated by `Heat` on every build.
PS : I know this question is repeated here a lot and I have read most of them, but I can't find out what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If files are generated by the running application then they won't be automatically removed on uninstall, any more than all your Word documents are deleted if you uninstall Office. If you did in fact install a DB (then populate it) then it is a candidate for removal at uninstall time.

Your major upgrade is after InstallExecute, which is towards the end of the upgrade process. This means that the new product will be installed on top of the existing product (and files), and that means that the file overwrite rules apply, and modified data files won't be overwritten:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370531(v=vs.85).aspx

The upgrade must have the same UpgradeCode as the previous product - it's not clear if it's the same or not.

Comment: The db file is created inside the application directory and It got erased.
In-fact the whole directory get removed

Yes, I use the same UpgradeCode.

Comment: I have found out the problem..
Simply  All files had version numbers, but I didn't change the assembly Info for each build, so It didn't replace the files.

Thank you for the hint

Comment: Yes, the file version overwrite rules apply so versions must be incremented. Glad you found it.